# Get rid of the default exporters with BenchmarkDotnet

Tags: c#, benchmarkdotnet

According to the [documentation](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/configs/exporters.html) BenchmarkDotnet's *Default exporters are: csv, html and markdown.*

I can see how to add my own exporter, but I can see how I can get rid of the default exporters.

If there is no way to do this, is the order that the exporters are run in guaranteed? In other words, will my additional exporter be guaranteed to run after the default ones?

Answer (score 1):

> how I can get rid of the default exporters

If you don't want the default settings,  you need to create an empty config and add everything you need in an explicit way. The minimal config that prints results to the console:

```cs
var config = ManualConfig.CreateEmpty()
    .AddColumnProvider(DefaultColumnProviders.Instance)
    .AddLogger(ConsoleLogger.Default);

// here you can add your exporter by using config.AddExporter()
// and pass it to BenchmarkRunner or BenchmarkSwitcher
```

I've created a PR that is going to make it easier in the next release: https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/pull/1582

Please feel free to create an issue in the BDN repo and suggest a new API|solution if you find the current solution too complex.

> is the order that the exporters are run in guaranteed?

It's guaranteed to be sorted by the dependencies requirements:

https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/blob/81c234d11cab1b3beb0e60cf0f5c4c92e60a41e6/src/BenchmarkDotNet/Configs/ImmutableConfigBuilder.cs#L117

An example is the `RPlot` exporter that relies on having the `CSV` exporter doing it's job first:

https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/blob/27887d4b612312c74c63c0c3220351f8db8e81e4/src/BenchmarkDotNet/Exporters/RPlotExporter.cs#L22-L26